# Dafny. Another case of call may violate context's modifies clause

Tags: dafny

I have read a lot of questions here and on the wiki about this, but I could not solve this "call may violate context's modifies clause" case. Could you help me? I am trying to send an instance of a problem to a "solver" from the main method, and when I call the `solve()` method, I get this error and I do not understand why. https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/53q6

```
class Stack {
  var x : array<int>;

  constructor()
    ensures fresh(x); 
  {
    x := new int[10];
  }
}

class Formula {
  var stack : Stack;

  constructor()
    ensures fresh(stack);
    ensures fresh(stack.x);
  {
    stack := new Stack();
  }
}

class Solver {
   var f : Formula;

  constructor(f' : Formula)
  {
    this.f := f';
  }

  method solve()
    modifies f.stack;

    ensures old(f.stack.x) == f.stack.x;
  {}
}

method Main() {
  var f := new Formula();
  var a := new Solver(f);
  assert fresh(f);
  assert fresh(f.stack);
  assert fresh(f.stack.x);
  assert fresh(a);
  a.solve();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the postcondition

```
ensures f == f'
```

on the constructor for the class `Solver`.

(Since constructors are methods, Dafny does not "look inside" their bodies when reasoning about other methods, so you need this postcondition to expose the body.)